# matching siblings according to tag attributes in xml using Python and libxml2

Tags: python, xpath, attributes, libxml2

I am new to programming and thus maybe lacking basics somewhere.

I have an xml:

```
<mother>
<daughter nr='1' state='nice' name='Ada'>
<daughter nr='2' state='naughty' name='Beta'>
<daughter nr='3' state='nice' name='Cecilia'>
<daughter nr='4' state='neither' name='Dora'>
<daughter nr='5' state='naughty' name='Elis'>
</mother>
```

what I need is to match naughty and nice daughters according to their number (the nice and her nearest naughty one) and print the pairs:

```
Ada Beta  
Cecilia Elis
```

my code:

```
import libxml2, sys

doc = libxml2.parseFile("file.xml")
tree = doc.xpathNewContext()

nice = tree.xpathEval("//daugter[@state='nice']")

for l in nice:
   print l.prop("name")

nice_nr = []
for n in nice:
    nice_nr.append(n.prop("nr"))

# and the same for the naugty daugters

doc.freeDoc()
```

So I am able to get the values of their attributes, but I am not able to figure out how to make pairs of them.
What I could find is the 'following-sibling' axis for Xpath but from all the examples I could find I am not sure whether it can be used here. The syntax is rather different and it takes all the following siblings.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy XPath solution. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
 /*/daughter[@state = 'nice'][1]
| 
 /*/daughter[@state = 'nice'][1]
       /following-sibling::daughter[@state='naughty'] [1]
```

This selects the pair of the first nice daughter and its nearest naughty daughter.

**To select the second such pair use:**

```
 /*/daughter[@state = 'nice'][2]
| 
 /*/daughter[@state = 'nice'][2]
       /following-sibling::daughter[@state='naughty'] [1]
```

... etc.

**Do note** that these expressions do not guarantee that a node will be selected at all -- there may be no `daughter` elements, or not every nice `daughter` element may have a following sibling `daughter` element that is naughty.

**If it is guaranteed that in the document the order** of `daughter` elements is strictly (`'nice'`, `'naughty`), then one can use a very simple XPath expression to get all pairs:

/*/daughter[@state = 'nice' or @state = 'naughty']

This selects all `daughter` elements that are children of the top element and have alternating state attribute with values: `nice, naughty, nice, naughty,` ...

**If the XPath API used gets these in an array of objects**, then for every even `k` the pair of daughters is in the kth and (k+1)th members of this array.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually each nice daughter has a naughty one in the loads of data I need to go through :) You see this is what confuses me on the 'next-sibling' axis. After copy/ pasting of your code I got an syntax error on the first line (/*/)

Comment: ^ (forgot to mention in the comment)

Comment: @zufanka: Thanks for your observation -- there was a missing ending quote for `'nice'` -- fixed now.

Comment: @zufanka: I updated my answer to reflect the latest information from you: now I give a simple XPath expression that gets all the pairs in a single array of objects. Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Each XPath expression will return a list of ordered nodes.  Just zip the lists together to find the corresponding pairs:

```
xpath = lambda state: tree.xpathEval("//daughter[@state='%s']" % state)
for nodes in zip(xpath('nice'), xpath('naughty')):
    print ' '.join(n.prop('name') for n in nodes)
```

Above, `xpath` is a function which evaluates the XPath expression which returns daughters matching the given `state`.  Then the two lists are passed to [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) which will return a tuple of the ith elements from each list.

If the daughter nodes are listed in the XML file out of order, you can sort the nodes by the `nr` attribute before passing them to `zip`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This actually works on the example I gave, but not in my code. I suspect the problem is that while one of the daughter elements uses "state='nice'", state of the other is "starts-with(@state,'nau')" -> because there are more values that I need to match. I get a libxml2.xpathError: xmlXPathEval() failed. I tried to re-write the code like ("//daughter[%s]" % state) and (xpath('@state="nice"'), xpath('starts-with(@state,"nau")')) but it doesn't work either

Comment: ^ (forgot to mention in the comment)

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution without xpath. The ordering of daughters by number is also taken into account. The doc is traversed only once.

```
from lxml.etree import fromstring

data = """the-xml-above""" 

def fetch_sorted_daughters(data):
    # load data into xml document
    doc = fromstring(data)
    nice = []
    naughty = []

    # extract into doubles - number, name
    for subelement in doc:
        if subelement.tag=='daughter':
            nr = subelement.get('nr')
            name = subelement.get('name')
            if subelement.get('state')=='nice':
                nice.append((nr, name))
            if subelement.get('state')=='naughty':
                naughty.append((nr, name))
    del doc # release document

    # sort doubles
    nice.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])
    naughty.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])

    # get sorted names from doubles 
    nice = tuple([double[1] for double in nice])
    naughty = tuple([double[1] for double in naughty])

    return nice, naughty

nice, naughty = fetch_sorted_daughters(data)
pairs = zip(nice, naughty)

print pairs
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.I would be most happy if I didn't have to use xpath :) but I need a wildcard in one of the cases in my code ( let's say that in the case of 'naughty' daughters the value of the state attribute has to starts with 'nau' to match also other daughters) and I coudln't find any solution for this in lxml.etree. The 'substring' or 'startswith' don't work there.

Comment: ^ (forgot to mention in the comment)